# Default sort order based on attribute of last object in has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a model for Company that looks like this

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :values
end
```

Then the Value model looks like this

```
class Value < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  default_scope order: 'created_at ASC'
end
```

I want to create a default sort order for Companies so that they are sorted based on the most recent values. Companies with the most recent values should be first. Something like this:

```
default_scope order: 'companies.values.last.created_at DESC'
```

But when I put that in my company model I get this error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near "values": syntax error: SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies"  WHERE "companies"."id" = ? ORDER BY companies.values.last.calculated_at DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include touch: true at the belongs_to :company association. This will update the updated_at column for the associated company whenever a value is added. Now you can just sort on the updated_at column.

```
class Value < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company, touch: true
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :values
 default_scope order: 'updated_at DESC'
end
```